# Ruby convert string to specific array format

Tags: ruby, regex

What I need to do is convert something like this:

```
"id,name,user[id,email]"
```

into this array:

```
["id", "name", {"user"=>["id", "email"]}]
```

What is the best way to do that? I think some function like `split` or `scan` can help, but I don't have much knowledge in regex to solve this.

Comment: Your expected array is invalid.

Comment: What is the context?  I think if you provide a bit more background on what you are trying to do, it might help.

Comment: @sawa Edited it to be more appropriated. Ruby converts `["id", "name", "user" => ["id", "email"]]` to `["id", "name", {"user"=>["id", "email"]}]`. In the example, user became a hash inside the array. You can try it typing my original array in console.

Comment: @steveklein I'm receiving a string in this pattern by query string on request, need to convert it to an array to I can use this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just out of curiosity:

```
▶ str = "id,name,user[id,email]"
▶ eval "[#{str.gsub(/(\w+)\[(.*?)\]/, '{\1=>[\2]}').gsub(/\w+/, ':\0')}]"
#⇒ [
#  [0] :id,
#  [1] :name,
#  [2] {
#    :user => [
#      [0] :id,
#      [1] :email
#    ]
#  }
#]
```

**Disclamer**: to use `eval` in production one must understand risks.

**UPD** Safe `eval`ing (note that every ASCII `\w` symbol is converted to it’s wide pair from UTF-8 to prevent injection; not the best way around, but it works nicely unless you have ruby functions named with wide characters):

```
▶ safe = str.gsub(/\w/) do |e| 
▷   e.each_codepoint.map do |cp| 
▷     cp + 0xFF00 - 0x0020
▷   end.pack('U')
▷ end
#⇒ "ｉｄ,ｎａｍｅ,ｕｓｅｒ[ｉｄ,ｅｍａｉｌ]"
▶ eval "[#{safe.gsub(/(\p{L}+)\[(.*?)\]/, '{\1=>[\2]}').gsub(/\p{L}+/, ':\0')}]"
#⇒ [
#  [0] :ｉｄ,
#  [1] :ｎａｍｅ,
#  [2] {
#    :ｕｓｅｒ => [
#      [0] :ｉｄ,
#      [1] :ｅｍａｉｌ
#    ]
#  }
#]
```

Now you are free to turn keys back from wide characters to ASCII.

Comment: Can I do exactly this without eval?

Comment: When I do eval on `safe` I'm getting: `undefined local variable or method `ｎａｍｅ'`

Comment: This error happens just in rails, on `irb` it does not happen. Will figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. This code probably requires some polishing, e.g. `@` may appear in email etc, it should be considered as a proof of concept only.

Comment: In my case I don't need `@` or any special characters, just strings. For me, it is perfect.

Comment: Inside rails the regex pattern `\w+` does not work with wide pairs. Do you know what I can do?

Comment: `\w` would not work with wides neither in rails nor in plain ruby. There is `\p{L}` matcher for utf-8 word characters. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties

Comment: Worked! Was using the same eval sentence of the first example. Is strange that in `irb` it worked. What about if I have some underscores? Example: `id,name,user_address[id,street_name]` -> `["id", "name", {"user_address"=>["id", "street_name"]}]`

Comment: There is no magic here. Either `[\p{L}_]` or combination of the `\p{}` matchers from the link I gave.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76566/discussion-between-william-weckl-and-mudasobwa).

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "id,name,user[id,email]"
parts = string.split(/[\,,\[,\]]/)
[parts[0], parts[1], {parts[2] => [parts[3], parts[4]]}]
```

You may also want to have some validation or not use all the parts if the first id is supposed to be the same as the second.

Comment: In my example case works. But what if I had `"user[id,email],id,name"`? The order can change, the number of strings can change, everything can change, my example is just a pattern. The @mudasobwa answer solves my problem but I did not want to use eval.

Comment: Why is it that "order can change, the number of strings can change, everything can change"?

Comment: @WilliamWeckl BTW, `eval` is not an evil. It might be used when you understand the circumstances. Absolutely safe usage: convert all `\w` to some utf-8, like wide characters ⇒ do eval ⇒ convert everything back.

Comment: @BSeven Because I'm receiving this by a query string in a request. In my request I'm saying what attributes I want to be returned in response but some attributes have nested inside.

Comment: @mudasobwa I'm sorry but I did not understand how can I do this:  convert all \w to some utf-8, like wide characters ⇒ do eval ⇒ convert everything back